# Retrieving an AWS EC2 Autoscaling Group name in Jenkins Groovy scripted pipeline from an ASG name prefix

Tags: bash, groovy, escaping, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to retrieve an AWS EC2 Autoscaling Group (ASG) name querying using the ASG name prefix in a Groovy scripted Jenkins pipeline.

So far I tried using AWS CLI inside the Groovy script but no luck. I think the main challenge I am facing is to handle quotes in 3 different levels in an `sh` command: 1) Sh command has to be surrounded by quotes 2) inside that the query string has to be surrounded by quotes and, 3)  inside that the value coming from the `asg_name_prefix` has to be surrounded by quotes.

Here is so far I did. If there is any other solution, I can accept unless the script is too complex and lengthy.

When I run the below line in bash, it retrieves the desired EC2 Autoscaling group name and stores in `asg_name`:

```
asg_name=$(aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query "AutoScalingGroups[?starts_with(AutoScalingGroupName, '${asg_name_prefix}')].AutoScalingGroupName" --output text | head -n 1)
echo "asg_name: $asg_name"
```

Output:

```
asg_name: my-app-asg-01
```

When I try using this in Groovy for Jenkins pipeline the following way, it does not retrieve the Aautoscaling group name:

```
def asg_name = sh(script: """ aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query "AutoScalingGroups[?starts_with(AutoScalingGroupName, '${asg_name_prefix}')].AutoScalingGroupName" --output text | head -n 1""", returnStdout: true).trim()
echo "asg_name: ${asg_name}"
```

It does not give any error, but the console output for this line shows like below:

```
21:34:43  [Pipeline] sh
21:34:43  + aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query AutoScalingGroups[?starts_with(AutoScalingGroupName, 'my-app-asg-')].AutoScalingGroupName --output text
21:34:43  + head -n 1
21:34:43  [Pipeline] echo
21:34:43  asg_name:
```

My understanding is that the `query` string part of this command has to be enclosed by quotes. So, I tried to escape double quotes the following way, but the behavior remains similar - does not work:

```
def asg_name = sh(script: """ aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query \"AutoScalingGroups[?starts_with(AutoScalingGroupName, '${asg_name_prefix}')].AutoScalingGroupName\" --output text | head -n 1""", returnStdout: true).trim()
echo "asg_name: ${asg_name}"
```

This time the console output for the above command shows the double quotes are not retained, and the pipelined `head -n 1` shows before the actual command:

```
21:59:29  [Pipeline] sh
21:59:29  + head -n 1
21:59:29  + aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query AutoScalingGroups[?starts_with(AutoScalingGroupName, 'my-app-asg-')].AutoScalingGroupName --output text
21:59:29  [Pipeline] echo
21:59:29  asg_name:
```

How can I make this working so that the autoscaling group name is stored in the Groovy variable `asg_name`?

Note:

1. Updated adding additional lines to show exact console output.
2. Changed the title and added more info to clarify my problem as I need a solution to retrieve the EC2 ASG name from a prefix. Main issue is not handling quotes in Jenkins.

**Final update that resolves this issue:**
After trying several times, I found that I did not use `--region` option. So, my syntax was right except it needed `--region <aws_region_name>` in the command.

Comment: And is the Groovy variable `asg_name` not what you want? The output looks like standard trace output from sh steps to me.

Comment: Hi @BenjaminW. - 1) Yes, I want the the Groovy variable `asg_name` to obtain the Autoscaling group name, but it does not, as you can see in my updated post. 2) Yes, that is the standard output in pipeline running console. My understanding is that the command will output the value of Autoscaling group name next to `asg_name` with `[Pipeline] echo` when the `[Pipeline] sh` output will show the query string quoted like `--query "AutoScalingGroups[....].AutoScalingGroupName"`

Comment: Have you tried using triple single quotes instead of triple double quotes? With double quotes, Groovy interprets `${asg_name_prefix}` as a variable.

Comment: Hi @IWilms - Yes, I did. With that the `$(asg_name}` variable still returns nothing, and the query string in the console log for the command shows like `--query AutoScalingGroups[?starts_with(AutoScalingGroupName, '')].AutoScalingGroupName`, meaning `${asg_name_prefix}` becomes empty.

Comment: @Rafiq, are you accepting alternative solution? i'm talking about groovy code to extract desired json value...

Comment: I need the first ASG name from the supplied  ASG name  prefix. Either code would work for that but should work, unless the code snippet is pretty large.

Comment: Hi @daggett - I changed the title of the question and added some more info so it becomes meaningful for my actual issue and acceptable resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use groovy to parse jsnon response from aws.

Let's assume that `aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --output json`

results something like:

```json
{
    "AutoScalingGroups": [
        {
            "AutoScalingGroupName": "other-app-asg-01",
            "AutoScalingGroupARN": "arn:aws:autoscaling:us-west-2:..."
        },
        {
            "AutoScalingGroupName": "my-app-asg-01",
            "AutoScalingGroupARN": "arn:aws:autoscaling:us-west-2:..."
        }
    ]
}
```

then in jenkins groovy following should work:

```js
def asg_json = sh("aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --output json", returnStdout: true)
asg_json = readJSON(text: asg_json)
def asg_name = asg_json.AutoScalingGroups.find{it.AutoScalingGroupName =~ /^my-app-asg-/}.AutoScalingGroupName
```

---

as troubleshooting model for your original question:

instead of `sh("""...""")` use `echo("""...""")` and ensure that in log output you have desired shell syntax

Comment: Hi @daggett - Thank you for your answer. This may fail retrieving the Autoscaling group when number of available ASG is >50. Yes, `--max-item` can be used, but that does not guarantee as well when the number of ASGs are unknown. Anyway, after trying several times, I found that I did not supply `--region`. So, my syntax was right except it needed `--region <aws_region_name>` in the command.